# 3Sum - Time Complexity

Tags: python, arrays

Given an array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Note:

The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Example:

```
Given array nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4],

A solution set is:
[
  [-1, 0, 1],
  [-1, -1, 2]
]
```

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        firstPointer = 0
        if len(nums) ==0:
            return []
        sum = 0
        sum = nums[0]
        numDict = {}
        result = []

        for i in nums:
            numDict[i] = numDict.get(i,0)+1 //Adding to Dict

        while firstPointer<len(nums):
            sum = nums[firstPointer]
            for index, value in enumerate(nums):
                if -(sum+value) in numDict and index!=firstPointer and index!=nums.index(-sum-value) and firstPointer!=nums.index(-sum-value):
                        add = [sum,nums[index],-(sum+value)] //Removing Duplicates
                        add.sort()
                        if add not in result:
                            result.append(add)

            firstPointer+=1


        return result
```

This code is passing 311/313 test-cases on leetcode. However, with an insanely long input array it gave a time limt exceed error. But the best solution for this problem is of O(n^2) complexity and my solution is pretty much O(n^2) right?

Comment: How long do you think `nums.index` takes?

Comment: It returns the index of the first element which checks out, so I'm guessing O(n) tops?
Hmm, I see what you mean. So the complexity here is n^4?! @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: [Find all triplets with zero sum](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-triplets-array-whose-sum-equal-zero/) provides description and code for three methods, two of which are O(n^2).

Comment: @DarrylG I’m aware of that. I wanted to know how much time my code is taking/and why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with `np.sort` and `np.unique` :

```
from itertools import combinations
```

---

```
list(set([tuple(sorted(comb)) 
          for comb in filter(lambda x: sum(x)==0,
                             combinations(array_nums,3))]))
#[(-1, -1, 2), (-1, 0, 1)]
```

---

```
list(map(list,set([tuple(sorted(comb)) 
                    for comb in filter(lambda x: sum(x)==0,
                                        combinations(array_nums,3))])))
#[[-1, -1, 2], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

Alternative using **@lenik method**:

```
l = []
ordered_arr = list(sorted(array_nums))
for i,val1 in enumerate(ordered_arr):
    if val1>0:
        break
    for val2 in ordered_arr[i+1:len(array_nums)-1]:
        sum1 = val1 + val2
        if sum1>0:
            break
        for val3 in ordered_arr[i+2:len(array_nums)]:
            tup = (val1, val2, val3)
            if (sum1 +val3) ==0 :
                l.append(tup)
list(set([tuple(sorted(comb)) for comb in l]))
```

**test**

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
array_nums = np.random.randint(-100 , 100, 400).tolist()
```

---

```
%%timeit
np.unique(list(map(np.sort,filter(lambda x: sum(x)==0,
                                   combinations(array_nums,3)))),
          axis=0).tolist()
```

Time:

```
2.93 s ± 136 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
list(set([tuple(sorted(comb)) 
          for comb in filter(lambda x: sum(x)==0,
                             combinations(array_nums,3))]))
```

Time:

```
2.66 s ± 66.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
l = []
ordered_arr = list(sorted(array_nums))
for i,val1 in enumerate(ordered_arr):
    if val1>0:
        break
    for val2 in ordered_arr[i+1:len(array_nums)-1]:
        sum1 = val1 + val2
        if sum1>0:
            break
        for val3 in ordered_arr[i+2:len(array_nums)]:
            tup = (val1, val2, val3)
            if (sum1 +val3) ==0 :
                l.append(tup)
list(set([tuple(sorted(comb)) for comb in l]))
```

Time:

```
1.34 s ± 87.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing. But what’s the significance of map here? And if it’s a list why .tolist() after that?

Comment: please, correct me, but `combinations( ..., 3)` has the complexity of O(N^3) ?

Comment: map here apply a function to each element of an array and return  an iterator , `tolist` in order to convert `np.array` to list

Answer (score 0):

The solution for a simpler problem, like `a+b = 0` takes a linear O(N) time with a presorted array or O(NlogN) if you need to sort it first. So here's a plan, you sort your array in O(NlogN), then do the following:

1. take the first element, name it 'C', solve `a+b = -C` in linear time.
2. take another element, name it 'C'....
3. keep going until all elements in the array were used up.

Overall, this will give you O(N^2) complexity.